# Bitbucket in http mode clones repo without password

Tags: git, bitbucket

I noticed that when i am trying to clone a private repo with command like : git clone http:// , it stopped asking me for password and clones the repo.

I checked ~/.gitconfig file and it do not contain my bitbucket password. It just contain email and name.

I have not set my bitbucket account to use SSH

What could be possible reason or location from where git is picking my password?

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: I am running OS X.

Comment: Perhaps password has been saved in Keychain if it's os x

Comment: Is there any way to check this or remove password from keychain?

Comment: @Celdor yes i see Mac Keychain saved my password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Behaviour** : Commandline do not prompt for password when cloning private repo.

**Root Cause**:  Mac Keychain stored my bitbucket password in its KeyChain utility.

**Solution**:  Remove your bitbucket password entry from KeyChain Utility.